# How many times can I disconnect without database operation after JDBC connection

Tags: java, database

```
int count = 0;
while(true) {
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

        Connection conn = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection(url);
          
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    count++;
}
```

I try to use this code to measure the maximum number of connections to the database, but the the Threads_connected of database increases first and then decreases. I found that when Threads_connected reaches a number, it suddenly becomes 0, then increases, so count will always increase. Why?

Comment: Hi, I don' t know if this is the good way (i need to see all the code). I see that you are using mySql. By default mySql can handle up to 151 connections. If you want to know more about MAX_CONNECTIONS and how to modify them, check [this](https://ubiq.co/database-blog/how-to-increase-max-connections-in-mysql/#:~:text=How%20Many%20Connections%20can%20MySQL,in%20server%20variable%20called%20max_connections)

Answer (score 0):

The DBMS cannot accept infinite number of connections. In your installation folder there surely is a configuration file where you can establish the maximum number of connections.

For example, PostgreSQL stores its config under "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL<version>\data\postgresql.conf" on Windows. The parameter in question is called "max_connections" and the PostgreSQL service needs to be restarted after changing the file.

Furthermore, as you mentioned in your question, most connections in idle will be terminated before accepting a new one, resulting in your count variable to overflow at some point.